# What do these lines of Unix/Linux do?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am a Unix/Linux shell script newbie and I have been asked to look at a script which contains the lines below. The following details in this question are vague but the person who wrote this code left no documentation and has since demised. Can anyone advise what they actually do?

There are two specific pieces of code. The first is simply line `source polys.sh` where `polys.sh` is a text file with contents:

```
failure="020o 040a"
success="002[a-d] 003[a-r] 004[a-s] 005[a-u]
```

Representing various parameters, I think, to do with the calculations the shell script performs. The nature of the calculations is, I am told, not important because the aim is to just get the script running.

The second piece of code is below and the relevant lines are delimited by `Start` and `Stop` comments. What I can tell you is that: `$arg1` is blank, `$opt1` is also blank, `$poly` is the path and name of a text file and `./search` I believe to be a folder.

```
if [ $search == "yes" ]
    then
      # Search stage for squares containing zeros
      #

      # Start.

      output="$outputs/search/"`basename $poly` 
      ./search $opt1 $arg1 < $poly 2>&1 | tee $output
      if tail -n1 $output | grep -v "success"

      # End.

      then
        echo "SEARCH FAILURE" >> $output
        continue
      fi
      # Save approximations
      #
      echo -n "SEARCH SUCCESS " >> $output
      cat /tmp/iters >> $output
      cp /tmp/zeros $inputs/search/`basename $poly`
    else
      echo "No search"
    fi
```

Comment: There are actually a lot of bugs in this snippet of code -- explaining both the intent *and the bugs* would take quite a bit of time and text, and there are many parts of it where their intent is obvious (though the aforementioned bugs may not be).

Comment: Please strip out everything here you already understand (surely you know what `echo` does), fix all the bugs that http://shellcheck.net shows, and ask a question focused on only what's left.

Comment: (There are issues that http://shellcheck.net/ doesn't find, too; it doesn't complain about `==` not being guaranteed to be valid in `[ ]`, despite the POSIX specification only describing `=` as a string comparison operator; it doesn't describe `echo -n` being explicitly undefined behavior per the POSIX spec for echo, with `printf` with an explicit format string as the preferred replacement... but fixing what it *does* identify is a good place to start).

Comment: ...and no, `./search` is not a directory ("folder" is Windows terminology), it's a separate script or command.

Comment: Then I shall check http://www.shellcheck.net/ but this is the code as written.

Comment: BTW, http://explainshell.com/ is another good resource, if you want a breakdown of what a single command does.

Comment: (checking for `success` in a program's output to tell if it was successful is also a code smell: A well-written program will reflect whether it was successful in its *exit status*, so you could just do something like `if ./search ...; then echo "search successful"; else echo "search failed"; fi`, perhaps with your script preceded by `set -o pipefail` if that `...` still includes piping output through `tee`; however, since the `search` command is something that exists local to you, we can't tell how well-written it is or isn't, and thus if it complies with these conventions).

Comment: Here's the thing: If you run, say, `foo $bar`, it can do any number of different things depending on the contents of `bar`; it might run `foo` with no arguments at all, it might treat the variable's contents as a glob and scan the filesystem to find matching filenames; it might then do any number of things depending on whether the glob matches and which script options (`failglob`, `nullglob`, etc) are present. `foo "$bar"` isn't subject to string-splitting or glob expansion, so the contents of `bar` will *always* be exactly one argument -- it's much more predictable, so it's easier to explain.

Comment: Thus, any explanation of buggy code will almost always be incomplete, because comprehensively explaining all the ways it can potentially behave would go on for pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Initial disclaimer as advised by Mr. Charles Duffy:

> The below explanations assume you won't hit expansion-related bugs; please correct your code as advised by [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) to be assured that these explanations are correct

- `source polys.sh` includes the code from the script `polys.sh`, which is a file in the same folder as the file sourcing it (hence just the filename, without its path).
- Within that file:

  ```
  failure="020o 040a"
  success="002[a-d] 003[a-r] 004[a-s] 005[a-u]"
  ```

  are two variable declarations; the variable `$failure` is set to `"020o 040a"` and `$success` to `"002[a-d] 003[a-r] 004[a-s] 005[a-u]"`. As the file was `source`d, these two variables are available in your script (do `echo "$failure"` and `echo "$success"` to see for yourself).
- `` output="$outputs/search/`basename $poly`" `` has two parts to explain:

  ```
  "$outputs/search/"
  ```

  sets the variable `$output` to `"$outputs/search/"`, i.e., to the value of the variable `$outputs`, appended by the string `"/search/"`.,

  ```
  `basename $poly`
  ```

  anything in backticks is a command substitution, which interprets and runs the command returning its output, and the command `basename $poly` gets the base file or folder name from `$poly`, if it is a file path (e.g., `basename $poly` for `poly="/dev/file.txt"` yields `file.txt`); the output is appended as a string. to `"$outputs/search/"`.
- `./search $opt1 $arg1 < $poly 2>&1 | tee $output` is two commands, separated by a pipe `|`:

  ```
  ./search $opt1 $arg1 < $poly 2>&1
  ```

  runs the executable file `./search` (`./` is shorthand for the current script's directory) with two arguments, `$opt1` and `$opt2` variables. `$poly` is the variable name which should represent a file path, of which the file path has its content redirected to the command (using `<`). The output of all errors (`stderr`, as `2`) is redirected (`>`) to the standard output (`stdout`, or `&2`, the ampersand represents this is a file descriptor, not a file path, otherwise it would redirect output to a file named `2`).

  ```
  tee $output
  ```

`tee` pipes outputs `stdin` to `stdout` and to arguments as file paths. So `tee "/home/nick/output"` would save the `stdin` to a file at `"/home/nick/output"`, as well as the `stdout`.

- `if tail -n1 $output | grep -v "success"`

  ```
  tail -n1 $output
  ```

  gets the last line of the file at the "$output" variable's value.

  ```
  grep -v "success"
  ```

  searches for any non-match (`-v` inverts the match) in the last line from `tail -n1` of `"success"` in a line (e.g., if the last line is `"fail"`, it would pass the `if` statement as it does not contain `"success"`)

Comment: Lots of assumptions in here about filenames being sane (not containing whitespace or glob characters), IFS being at default values, etc. Which is to say, you're describing what its author *intended* this code to do, not what it's guaranteed to *actually* do when it's run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is an explanation of the code and commands, no commentary on its quality.

Comment: Sure, but is it really an explanation if it leaves out possible behaviors? "This does X" is only an entirely true statement if the code is guaranteed to actually do X.

Comment: Thanks. You've both given me a lot of food for though, so to speak. I will return to this issue later today or tomorrow.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry if it appears I'm making assumptions about the variables - perhaps anything you feel I should clear up you could point out/edit. I'm basically trying to explain how the command interprets each variable, not saying that the variable definitely represents that - obviously it might not if the user of the command is a doughnut, in which case you'll have problems.

Comment: Sure -- the problem is that without adequate quoting, how the variables are going to be interpreted is dependent both on their content and on the current value of IFS (thus, the context) -- and, if any of those variables, when split on IFS, evaluate as globs, depend on filesystem options, the state of the `nullglob`, `failglob`, and similar options, etc. Frankly, an up-front "the below explanations assume you won't hit expansion-related bugs; please correct your code as advised by http://shellcheck.net/ to be assured that these explanations are correct" waiver or similar may suffice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've worded the answer so what the variables should represent is more clearly stated, without such assumptive tone as to what they are.

Comment: I'm still not sure this really adequately covers the failure cases. Consider the behavior of `basename $poly` when `poly='/some/filename with spaces and a * glob'`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Excellent commentary, I didn't even consider that! Thank you, I've added the disclaimer. Definitely some food for thought for myself on answering bash-related questions.

Comment: ...or of `basename $poly` when `poly=/some/file123.txt` but `IFS=.`